# How to find webelement using style property in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to give Click the button based on style and class name,because in my case there is no unique class name and id.

My html code is

```
<a class="x-btn x-unselectable rp-important-btn rp-btn-shadow x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon" 
style="height: 24px; right: auto; top: 5px; margin: 0px; left: 118px;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" tabindex="0">
```

And i have tried

```
 save_class=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-important-btn rp-btn-shadow x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' 
 and style='height: 24px; right: auto; top: 5px; margin: 0px; left: 118px;']")
```

I am getting following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable
>   rp-important-btn rp-btn-shadow x-box-item x-toolbar-item
>   x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon'
>   and style='height: 24px; right: auto; top: 5px; margin: 0px; left:
>   118px;']"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot `@style` in your xpath

```
save_class=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-important-btn rp-btn-shadow x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @style='height: 24px; right: auto; top: 5px; margin: 0px; left: 118px;']")
```

Try this!

Answer (score 0):

Hi to choose with two match attribute and click the button use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="x-btn x-unselectable rp-important-btn rp-btn-shadow x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon" and @style="height: 24px; right: auto; top: 5px; margin: 0px; left: 118px;"').click()
```

Comment: My case class is not a unique one.and i want to check style also